# JSON object and Multipart file upload not working

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

We have Angular Controller as follows

```
$scope.uploadData = function (files, data) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("CustomerName", "Mahesh"); //As of now mocking the entities for creating form data 
                fd.append("CustomerID ", "44444");
                fd.append("ProductList",  JSON.stringify([{ProductID: '0001', ProductName: 'Samsung'},{ProductID: '0002', ProductName: 'Voldats'}]));
                fd.append("file", files[0]);
                fd.append("file", files[1]);
                inventoryService.Postfile(fd);                    
            }
```

Restangular post as follows

```
Postfile : function (formData) {
                return restangular.all("postfile").withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity}).customPOST(formData, '', undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined});
                 },
```

Java VOs as follows

```
public class ProductList implements Serializable{
private String ProductID;
private String ProductName;

public String getProductID() {
    return ProductID;
}

public void setProductID(String productID) {
    ProductID = productID;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return ProductName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    ProductName = productName;
}

}
```

and

```
public class CustomerList implements Serializable{
String CustomerName;
String CustomerID;
List<ProductList> ProductList;

public String getCustomerName() {
    return CustomerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    CustomerName = customerName;
}

public String getCustomerID() {
    return CustomerID;
}

public void setCustomerID(String customerID) {
    CustomerID = customerID;
}

public List<ProductList> getProductList() {
    return ProductList;
}

public void setProductList(List<ProductList> productList) {
    ProductList = productList;
}
}
```

Spring controller as follows

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/postfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
IhmsVO postfile(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "data") CustomerList vo, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    System.out.println("Post file");
    System.out.println(vo.getProductList());
    System.out.println("Files :: " + files + "  " + files.size());
    return null;
}
```

We have uploaded two files and JSON Object, CustomerName and CustomerID mapped properly with corresponding VO, but ProductList not mapped with the VO.We are getting null in ProductList, Debug mode screenshot attached for refrence. May help to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Blob with correct content type to pass the JSON data and add it to the form (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob), e.g.:

```
fd.append("ProductList",  new Blob([ JSON.stringify([{ProductID: '0001', ProductName: 'Samsung'},{ProductID: '0002', ProductName: 'Voldats'}]) ], { type: "application/json" }));
```

EDIT: Updated the code to be absolutely clear and avoid any typos, case sensitivity issues, wrong placement of parenthesis etc.

Comment: we are actually using angular to build the application. we have tried as you have suggested. But we are getting the following exception in the angular.      TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties.(…)

Comment: Actually, you have to embed the stringified json into array, i.e. new Blob(**[** JSON.stringify(...) **]**, { type: ... });

Comment: We have modified as you suggested, i.e. new Blob([ JSON.stringify(...) ], { type: ... }), Error rectified. But still we are getting null in ProductList in Spring controller. Is it require to change in anything in spring controller?